# 1D Peak Finding Algorithm in Python using Divide and Conquer

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement an 1D peak algorithm in python, though I am having troubles implementing it. The idea is that it compares the central term of the array and picks the side with the higher neighbour term. That half becomes the new array. Only when the central is the largest term, does it become the peak. Here is my code: 
import math

```
import math

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
size = len(array)
count = 0

while count == 0: 
    if len(array) == 2:
        count += 1
        print(max(array[0],array[1])) 
        break
    elif count == 0: 
        elif array[math.floor(abs(size/2))] < array[math.floor(abs(size/2))-1]:
            new_array = [] 
            for i in range(int(abs(size)/2)):
                new_array.append(array[i])
                array = new_array
        elif array[math.floor(abs(size/2))] < array[math.floor(abs(size/2))+1]:
            new_array = []
            for j in range(math.floor(abs(size)/2),size): 
                new_array.append(array[j])
            array = new_array
        elif count == 0: 
            count += 1
            print(array[math.floor(abs(size/2))])
            break
```

I keep on getting errors, and I can not seem to identify the problem. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem (aside from compuphy's catch) is the fact that you don't change your variable "size" upon resizing your array, which is liable to lead to IndexErrors. Also, a few nitpicks:

1. There's no point in doing abs(size/2), since it'll always be
   positive.
2. Instead of floor(size/2), if this is python 3, just do
   size//2 for integer division, or if it's python 2, just size/2 will
   suffice.
3. The way your program is implemented makes the runtime greater than O(logN), which I assume you're targeting, so I think you should look into implementations where you keep an upper and lower bound of the subarray you're searching rather than making a new array in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have **elif's** in the first **elif** condition but without any preceeding **if's**:

```
elif count == 0: 
        elif array[math.floor(abs(size/2))] < array[math.floor(abs(size/2))-1]:
        ^^^^
```

try changing those to `if`

Comment: I tried that, which fixes one problem, but the followinf error keeps coming up:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PeakFinder1D.py", line 21, in <module>
    elif array[math.floor(abs(size/2))] < array[math.floor(abs(size/2))+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range